# How do you enable Trace Rollover for audit traces on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, audit

I need to find out if Trace Rollover is enabled on my SQL Server 2005 machine. Where can I find this out and turn it on if I need to?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new trace you'll see the "Trace Properties". On the General tab select "Save to file". Then you can set the max. file size & mark the "Enable file rollover" box.

EDIT: This is not a general setting, but is on a per-trace basis.